# Declaring variables clears the parameters

Tags: c++, pointers

So, I am building a mockup of a licensing-system in C++.

```
char * LicenseServer::CreateHash (char* key)
{
    char* newHash = nullptr;

    //Create the hash if new key.
    if (key != m_Key)
    {
        char* macAddr = GetMACAddress ();

        size_t seed = 0;

        boost::hash_combine (seed, std::string(key));
        boost::hash_combine (seed, std::string(macAddr));

        if (seed == size_t(0))
            return nullptr;

        std::stringstream sed;
        sed << seed;
        std::string seedstr = sed.str();

        newHash = new char[seedstr.length() + 1];
        strcpy_s (newHash, seedstr.length() + 1, seedstr.c_str ());
    }

    return newHash;
}
```

I am coming upon a strange error, though: every time I try to infer the declaration of a new char*, my input parameter "key", changes to an empty string.

It currently happens when I get to the strign-stream. Upon "std::stringstream sed", the key variable becomes "". Not null, but "".

It happened previously in the fucntion GetMACAddress as well, where I had declared

```
char newthing[4096]
```

Here it was solved by declaring

```
char* newthing = new char[4096];
```

It did not mirror the new content which I then put into newthing, just stayed "".

**Why is the input parameter just casually cleared like this?**

I am currently building in visual studio 2017, target 15063, on the c++latest tag.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:for a smaller code sample.

Comment: Is `key != m_Key` supposed to compare two strings, or to compare two pointers? What is `m_Key`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And why are you using `char *` for some strings and `std::string` for other strings? Use `std::string` for *all* strings.

Comment: is "m_Key" a char* too? do yourself a favour, use std::string

Comment: Probably a memory bug , either in here or in code elsewhere. Don't bother debugging, it likely is the result of not using std:: string. So switch to that.

Comment: because the program I am appending to is more than 20 years old, and habits are hard to shake. That is my bad. 

While it might maybe solve the problem, it does not satisfy my curiosity, though. Why does the char* parameter get cleared just because I declare a stringstream?

Comment: @KasperIngdahlAndkjær you should run a sanitizer on your code. You probably have undefined behavior.

Comment: How does `CreateHash()` get called? I'd guess there is a missing null-terminator, so additional content of the stack seems to belong to the string, until you create a local variable with value zero, which effectively terminates the string. But this is only a guess until you show the calling code.